# Why do these solution graphs not match each other?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, surfaces, mathematica, discrete-geometry

Consider the Initial Value Problem, $\frac{dP}{dt} = ((1 + f)^\frac{3}{5} (1 - f)^\frac{2}{5} - 1)P,\ P(0) = 100$, where $f$ is a real parameter between $0$ and $1$, inclusive.  Its solution is $P = 100e^{(1\ +\ f)^\frac{3}{5} (1\ -\ f)^\frac{2}{5}t\ -\ t}$.

The discrete analog to this Initial Value Problem is $P[n + 1] = ((1 + f)^\frac{3}{5} (1 - f)^\frac{2}{5} - 1)P[n],\ P[0] = 100$.  Its solution is $P = 100((1 + f)^\frac{3}{5} (1 - f)^\frac{2}{5} - 1)^n$.  Note that $f$, and thus $P$, are still continuous; only the independent variable has been discretized.

I would expect the graphs of the two solutions to resemble each other; the former is a surface, and the latter should look like a parallel succession of slices of the same surface.  However, this is the actual geometry...

[image]

There is some unrelated issue with improper scaling of $f$ in the second graph.  However, it is still pretty clear that the latter is not a discrete version of the former.  Why is it not?

Comment: The two solutions are very different functions. I wouldn't expect them to look the same.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Is it not the case that a difference equation solution is supposed to converge to the corresponding differential equation solution in the limit of incorporating more and more slices into the graph?

Comment: Are you confident those are the solutions? If so it then you've got a counter-example.

Comment: The forward Euler solution converges slowly to the continuous solution, with numerical instabilities for too large step sizes. But what you implemented is not even the Euler method. $P'=(N(f)-1)P$ discretized with step size 1 should read $P[n+1]=P[n]+(N(f)-1)P[n]=N(f)P[n]$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Right, I was not trying to implement Euler's Method.  I was trying to match the linear differential equation and linear difference equation which have the same characteristic equation and thus the same eigenstructure.  Is this not a valid approach?

Comment: No, that makes no sense. The roots for the linear DE give factors in the exponents $e^{\lambda t}$, the roots for the difference equation give basis values for a geometric sequence $q^n$, you should recognize the difference.